# What's the trick to inspect popout / dropdown menu style with Firebug?

Tags: css, firebug, drop-down-menu

Is there a way to make a popout menu 'stick' when inspecting with Firebug.

You can do it with Chrome, but I prefer firebug.

It's hard to set padding or a margin when you can't see the element you are styling.

I did some research but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an option built in:

[image]

Inspect the element that's "hidden", then use this.

Answer (score -1):

You can show/hide them using JS console, directly using `show()` or binding an event(mouseover, click etc).