# Inspect the Markup used in CKEditor Styles Dropdown

Tags: ckeditor, firebug, inspect

I want to inspect the markup of CKEditors Styles Dropdown.
The problem is, I can't click firebugs 'inspect'-button, because the dropdown immediately closes when clicking somewhere outside of it.

I want to see what exact markup is being used so I can style it better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the trick to inspect popout / dropdown menu style with Firebug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462016/whats-the-trick-to-inspect-popout-dropdown-menu-style-with-firebug)

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/q/22125954/432681?

Comment: pretty close but not primarily related to CKE. Still the answer I gave there also helped out in my case here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it even if it is a little tricky.

If you are using Chrome you can press F8 while having the developer tools opened. F8 pauses on next script execution.

So if you hover over the desired element, then press F8, then move your mouse a bit inside/over the element, the script execution will pause with that dropdown opened and you will be able to rightclick -> inspect it, as long as in pause.